# Netbeans: How do you remove the icons in the number lines?

Tags: netbeans, ide

See the image for better understanding.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The light bulb icon is a hint *annotation*, and the hints displayed/marked are controlled in ***Tools* > *Options* > *Editor* > *Hints***. Select the appropriate language and uncheck those hints you don't want displayed.

[image: Image courtesy Netbeans.org, Code Assistance reference page]

The green icon is an override *annotation*. it indicates that the function/method in the child class overrides one of the same name in the parent class. Annotations, in general, are formatted in ***Tools* > *Options* > *Fonts & Colors* > *Annotations***.

[image]

(Note that the light bulb hint annotation is just another annotation.) I am not familiar with a way to turn off these annotations, or a way to turn off annotations in general.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I already disabled all the hints in the options and it's still showing up.

See this image for reference: http://i.imgur.com/ieT9B.png

I am not sure but it looks like a bug to me.

Comment: My guess is that the remaining hint annotation on the first line is from the "HTML error checking...disabled" and "HTML version cannot be determined" hints. There does not seem to be a way to turn those particular hints off, apparently.